# What does %öäüß in the 2nd line of PDF files mean?

Tags: pdf

If I view a PDF file in a hex editor, I see these 2 first lines:

```
%PDF-1.6  
%öäüß
```

The first line, as explained in the [spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), is the PDF version number.

What is the significance of the second line? I couldn't find it in the spec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PDF files `%` starts a comment so that's just a useless string. Many PDF generators use it to *prevent the file from being messed up* by buggy programs

But how? Some applications check whether a file is text or binary heuristically by checking the first blocks of data (usually 512, 1024 or 2048 bytes) and measure the percent of non-printable or invalid characters. Some others are not [8-bit clean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean). Therefore it's recommended to put at least 4 bytes with values above 127 in the first 512 bytes to force those apps to recognize the file as binary. Otherwise bad things happen like converting between CRLF and LF, truncating of the top bits or removing invalid UTF-8 byte sequences (if the file was recognized as UTF-8 text)

> What follows are some ASCII characters that are using non-printable characters (note the ‘.’ dots), which are usually there to tell some of the software products that the file contains binary data and shouldn’t be treated as 7-bit ASCII text
>
> https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/pdf-file-format-basic-structure/#gref

It's actually recommended by the PDF standard

> **Note:** *If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do (see Section 3.1, “Lexical Conventions”), it is recommended that the header line be immediately followed by a comment line containing at least four binary characters—that is, characters whose codes are 128 or greater. This ensures proper behavior of file transfer applications that inspect data near the beginning of a file to determine whether to treat the file’s contents as text or as binary.*

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

> If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do (see 7.2, Lexical Conventions"), the header line shall be immediately followed by a comment line containing at least four binary characters—that is, characters whose codes are 128 or greater. This ensures proper behaviour of file transfer applications that inspect data near the beginning of a file to determine whether to treat the file’s contents as text or as binary.

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Some sources about PDF that I've read say that some programs are still not convinced that the file is binary without zero bytes, but unfortunately you can't embed zeros in PDF comments. I can't find them right now so I'll quote later